# Design encouraging FK to non-unique/non-PK

Tags: sql-server, database-design, foreign-key, azure-sql-database

My current design is makes me want to create a FK to a non-unique/non-PK. **Is this a code smell and/or does my overall design make sense?**

```
CREATE TABLE [User].[ConnectionRequest]
(
    [ConnectionRequestId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    [Requestor] INT NOT NULL, -- FK to internal user table
    [Target] INT NOT NULL, -- FK to ConnectionRequestTarget table
    [Status] INT NOT NULL, -- FK to status enum descriptions
    [Created] DATETIME2(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT SYSUTCDATETIME(),

    CONSTRAINT [FK_Name_Truncated_For_Space] 
      FOREIGN KEY ([Target]) 
      REFERENCES [User].[ConnectionRequestTarget]([ConnectionRequestTargetId]),     
    CONSTRAINT [Unique_ConnectionRequest_Target_Status] UNIQUE ([Target], [Status])
    -- Other FK's removed for brevity
)

CREATE TABLE [User].[ConnectionRequestTarget]
(
    [ConnectionRequestTargetId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    [InternalUserId] INT NULL, -- FK to internal user table, can be updated
    [ReferralId] INT NULL, -- FK to referral table
    [RequestCreated] DATETIME2(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT SYSUTCDATETIME(),
    -- FK's removed for brevity
);

CREATE TABLE [User].[PushSent]
(
    [PushSentId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    [MatchingToken] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [PushDeviceId] INT NOT NULL,
    [Category] INT NOT NULL,
    [MonitoringId] INT NULL,
    [ConnectionRequestTargetId] INT NULL,
    [ThresholdForNextAlert] DATETIME2(2) NULL,
    [Scheduled] DATETIME2(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT SYSUTCDATETIME(),
    [Sent] DATETIME2(2) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [FK_PushSent_ConnectionRequestTargetId_to_ConnectionRequest_Target] 
       FOREIGN KEY ([ConnectionRequestTargetId]) 
       REFERENCES [User].[ConnectionRequest]([Target]), -- This doesn't work
    -- Other FK's and check constraints removed for brevity
);
```

The `ConnectionRequest` table contains a history of the connection requests and their status updates. I normalized the `target` of the connection request into its own table so the target details wouldn't be duplicated with each status update. For example:

```
-- ConnectionRequest table sample data
ConnectionRequestId | Requestor | Target | Status | Created
        1                 1         1        1      2015-10-3 10:31:23.93 -- Request Pending
        2                 2         2        1      2015-10-3 10:31:25.89 -- Request Pending
        3                 1         3        1      2015-10-3 11:45:12.49 -- Request Pending
        4                 1         1        3      2015-10-3 12:45:12.49 -- Request Accepted
        5                 1         4        1      2015-10-3 12:45:12.49 -- Request Pending

-- ConnectionRequestTarget table sample data
ConnectionRequestTargetId | InternalUserId | ReferralId | RequestCreated
          1                       3             NULL      2015-10-3 10:31:23.93 -- Internal
          2                       3             NULL      2015-10-3 10:31:25.89 -- Internal
          3                      NULL            1        2015-10-3 11:45:12.49 -- External
          4                       4              2        2015-10-3 12:45:12.49 -- Updated
```

As you can see connection status updates are handled by inserting a new row into the `ConnectionRequest` table. The `(Target, Status)` `UNIQUE` constraint in the `ConnectionRequest` table is there to ensure a `Target` doesn't get multiple entries for the same status. Furthermore a new `ConnectionRequestTarget` is generated for each request even if the user being targeted is the same. The `InternalUserId` column in the `ConnectionRequestTarget` table can be updated if the target wasn't a user, and then creates an account.

This worked great until a requirement came in to periodically prompt users with a push notification if they haven't acted<sup>(accept/deny)</sup> on a connection request. Due to that request I want to put a FK into the `PushSent` table which will let me track the number of pushes sent to a target.

I can't set the FK to the `Target` column in the `ConnectionRequest` table because it is non-unique by design. I know I can put the `Status` flag into the `PushSent` table with the `Target`, or handle this with a [UDF and a check constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26427936/5190842), but those options feel a bit dirty. I could also specify a FK to the `ConnectionRequestTarget` table directly from the `PushSent` table but that could open the door for associating pushes to an orphaned target.

In truth it gets a bit more complicated than this because a `Target` of a `ConnectionRequest` can be a current member, or a potential member, but the core requirement to track the count of pushes/contacts to a `Target` remains.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me you have an entity *Target* against which you may have an active *ConnectionRequest*. It would appear that the Status of a request will be changed from time to time as the request is processed. In that case, that field should not be made part of any key or unique constraint. Only stable (unchanging) fields should be part of a key. In this case, it would appear that the *Created* field would be perfect.

However, I don't see why you need to create a unique constraint at all. You already assign a unique PK to each request, why don't you have *ConnectionRequestTargetId* refer to *ConnectionRequest( ConnectionRequestID )*? This would safely tie each *PushSent* to one specific request.

Comment: The fields (Target, Status) do not make a good key, for the reason I stated. Instead, (Target, Created) would be a better candidate. Also, You are trying to create a FK from PushSent to Connection request. But this isn't working because you are using the non-unique field Target. You don't want to have the PushSent record refer to the target, but to the connection request. The request refers to the target. So in your FK constraint definition in the PushSent table, change Target to ConnectionRequestId.

Comment: I agree that `(Target, Status)` don't make a good FK, which is why I initially dismissed it in my question.  I disagree that `(Target, Created)` would be a better key. I understand why I can't put a FK on `Target`, which is what I stated in my question. I agree that `ConnectionRequestId` is the better key as suggested by @ypercube in the comments, and confirmed by myself in the comments.  I've also updated my question to give more reasons why I decided to give `(Target, Status)` a `UNIQUE` constraint.

Comment: A connection request is made by a requester for a target. So you want to make the status unique for each target even across different requesters. What are some examples of status values? Surely, *Pending* can't be one because it would be reasonable to have several requests in that status at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the comment by ypercube](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116836/design-encouraging-fk-to-non-unique-non-pk#comment212599_116836):

> Why does the `Target` need to be in the `PushSent` table? Can't you just use a `ConnectionRequestId` column instead (which would be an FK to `ConnectionRequest`)?

I realized I was approaching this problem wrong. I had focused on the `Target` relationship until I developed tunnel vision.

In the end I decided against holding a FK to the `ConnectionRequest` table or `ConnectionRequestTarget` table in my `PushSent` table.  I ended up creating the table below instead to record each contact attempt:

```
CREATE TABLE [Log].[ContactAttempt]
(
    [ContactAttemptId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Method] INT NOT NULL, -- FK to enum description table, 1 = SMS, 2 = Email, 3 = Push
    [ConnectionRequestId] INT NOT NULL, -- FK to ConnectionRequest table
    [Created] DATETIME2(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT SYSUTCDATETIME()
    -- FK definitions removed for brevity
)
```

Using that table I could get the information I needed using the following query:

```
DECLARE @Now DATETIME2(2) = CAST(SYSUTCDATETIME() AS DATETIME2(2));
;WITH [NotificationCount_CTE] AS
(
    SELECT
        [CR].[ConnectionRequestId]
        , DATEADD(DAY, 1, [CR].[Created]) AS [FirstCutoff]
        , DATEADD(DAY, 4, [CR].[Created]) AS [SecondCutoff]
        , DATEADD(DAY, 7, [CR].[Created]) AS [ThirdCutoff]
        , CASE -- This could probably be improved
            WHEN MAX([CA].[Created]) > DATEADD(DAY, 7, [CR].[Created]) THEN 4 
            ELSE CASE WHEN MAX([CA].[Created]) > DATEADD(DAY, 4, [CR].[Created]) THEN 3
            ELSE CASE WHEN MAX([CA].[Created]) > DATEADD(DAY, 1, [CR].[Created]) THEN 2
            ELSE 1 END END
          END AS [ContactCount] -- Use a CASE statements so early counts aren't 
                                -- included in the filter below
    FROM [User].[ConnectionRequest] [CR]
        LEFT JOIN [Log].[ContactAttempt] [CA] ON 
           [CA].[ConnectionRequestId] = [CR].[ConnectionRequestId]
    WHERE
        [CR].[Status] = 1 -- Pending status.
    GROUP BY
        [CR].[ConnectionRequestId]
        , [CR].[Created]
)
SELECT
    [PDA].[DeviceToken]
    , ISNULL([PDA].[PushDeviceId], 0) AS [PushDevice]
    , [PDA].[PushSystem]
    , CASE WHEN [CCR].[InternalUserId] IS NULL THEN [CCR].[ContactInfo] 
          ELSE ISNULL([SU].[Email], [U_T].[PhoneNumber]) 
      END AS [ContactInfo] -- External users invititation contact. 
                           -- Internal users use email first, phone number second.
    , [U_R].[Fullname] -- Name of person who initiated contact request
    , [U_R].[DisplayName] -- Fall back if they didn't provide a full name
    , [PDA].[CurrentPushCount]
    , [CR].[ConnectionRequestId] AS [RequestId]
    , [CCR].[ReferralCode] -- Code for tracking external invites via a link
FROM [User].[ConnectionRequest] [CR]
    INNER JOIN [User].[CurrentConnectionRequestStatus] [CCR] ON 
       [CCR].[Target] = [CR].[Target]
    INNER JOIN [NotificationCount_CTE] [NC] ON 
       [NC].[ConnectionRequestId] = [CR].[ConnectionRequestId]
    LEFT JOIN [User].[CurrentPushDeviceAssociation] [PDA] WITH (NOEXPAND) ON 
       [PDA].[UserId] = [CCR].[InternalUserId]
    LEFT JOIN [User].[User] [U_R] ON 
       [U_R].[UserId] = [CCR].[Requestor]
    LEFT JOIN [User].[User] [U_T] ON 
       [U_T].[UserId] = [CCR].[InternalUserId]
    LEFT JOIN [Security].[User] [SU] ON 
       [SU].[UserId] = [CCR].[InternalUserId]
WHERE
    [CCR].[Status] = 1 -- We only remind if the request is still pending
    AND
    (
        (@Now > [NC].[FirstCutoff] AND [NC].[ContactCount] = 1)
        OR
        (@Now > [NC].[SecondCutoff] AND [NC].[ContactCount] = 2)
        OR
        (@Now > [NC].[ThirdCutoff] AND [NC].[ContactCount] = 3)
    );
```

The `CurrentConnectionRequestStatus` reference is a view that shows the current status for the connection, and denormalizes some of the associated data.

The key insight besides the one [provided by ypercube](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116836/design-encouraging-fk-to-non-unique-non-pk#comment212599_116836) was that I really didn't want/need a true push/contact count. What I really wanted was to see if any contact attempt was made at certain intervals. By combining the various contact methods into one table I could easily track what methods of contact had been attempted, and when they were attempted.

---

### To explicitly answer my original question:

1. Is this a code smell?

   - Yes, this was a code smell caused by my tunnel vision. Once my eyes were opened I was able to eliminate the apparent conflict.
2. Does my overall design make sense?

   - The overall design needed to be tweaked to cleanly reflect the requirements.